# Multi term synonyms not working for the Solr on french site

Tags: solr

Using the Drupal 7.39 and Solr 3.5(Search Api module) for the french site, the keywords search for is working as required, it returns the required records on using the keywords searched.

But on using the multi term synonyms the searched is not working properly. Below are some of the content of the synonyms_fr.txt file

> Responsable Resources Humaines, Responsable RH
>
> Consultant Ressources Humaines, Consultant RH, Conseiller Ressources
>   Humaines, Conseiller RH
>
> Directeur du développement RH, Directeur du developpement des
>   Ressources Humaines, Directeur de la gestion prévisionnelle des
>   emplois et des compétences
>
> Directeur de programmes, Directeur de projets Head of Retention,
>   Retention Manager

On searching "Responsable RH" or "Responsable Resources Humaines" the solr returns proper data. But using "Directeur du développement RH" it return say "X" number or records but with it synonmys value "Directeur du developpement des Ressources Humaines" it returns 0 records with "Directeur de la gestion prévisionnelle des emplois et des compétences" it returns "X-1" numbers of records.

Not able to understand the why the multi-term synonmys not working.

Below is the solr configuration for the french site.

```
<fieldType name="text_fr" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
<analyzer type="index">
  <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt" />
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords_fr.txt" format="snowball" ignoreCase="true" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" protected="protwords.txt" preserveOriginal="1" />
  <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms_fr.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
  <filter class="solr.FrenchLightStemFilterFactory" />
  <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
</analyzer>
<analyzer type="query">
  <charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory" mapping="mapping-ISOLatin1Accent.txt" />
  <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory" />
  <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords_fr.txt" format="snowball" ignoreCase="true" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
  <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" splitOnCaseChange="1" splitOnNumerics="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" protected="protwords.txt" preserveOriginal="1" />
  <filter class="solr.FrenchLightStemFilterFactory" />
  <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
</analyzer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Multi term synonyms is complicated and doesn't work very well.
I'm using 
https://github.com/healthonnet/hon-lucene-synonyms
and it's working well.

But you could first maybe investigate more your configuration if you provide us the results of the analysis of the diffent words you are searching for.
Furthermore when you say "Responsable RH" do you mean the phrase query or is it to emphasize the example in your text?

Comment: Yes "Responsable RH" is a phrase query.